# How to build a 1-hour replay stream buffer in Flink?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like to dynamically keep a buffer of the last 1-hour events. That buffer should give me a replay function so that queries can be executed on the last-hour data. 
Is there already something implemented within Flink? Or do I need to build it myself?

I tried to use the Window API but it seems that Flink doesn't give me a forward shifting fixed width time window.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to my own question but I would like to keep the question in case you have better solutions. Because mine definitely violates some of the good practices of functional programming.

My hack is the following.

```
            val keyedEventStream: KeyedStream[E]

            // create a stream of [hourly window as a set of events]
            val eventWindowStream = keyedEventStream.timeWindow(Time.minutes(60), Time.milliseconds(50)).fold(scala.collection.Set[E]())((set: scala.collection.Set[E], event: E) => set + event)


            // This is the hourly buffer my process logic will use
            var workWindow = scala.collection.Set[E]()
            // update the workspace window with the stream of hourly window.
            eventWindowStream.map((set: scala.collection.Set[W]) => workWindow = set)
```

As you can see, the only purpose of last map is to update the variable workWindow, which is actually a side effect of the inline function...